# How do I change specific parts of tkinter backround app?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, background-color

I want to change the backround color of my app, the current way I have it is like this:
[image]

They way I want my app too look like is something similar to this:
[image]

you can see how it has some different colors to it for example on top the whole area looks a bit grayish, and I'd like to see how it can be done,
this is my code:

```
root.title("Arizon")
root.geometry("620x400+0+0")
root.configure(bg='#1c1b1c')
heading = Label(root, text="Arizon Updater", font=("arial", 40, "bold"), fg="#030208", bg= "#1c1b1c").pack()
label1 = Label(root, text="Enter how much minimum value do u want to gain: ", font=("arial", 9, "bold"), fg="#f0f0f5", bg="#141314").place(x=5, y=90)
```

Comment: The `heading` uses the same background color as `root`.  Try changing root color to `#131413`.

Comment: You cannot use two different geometry managers in the same frame! Geometry managers also return `None`

Comment: @Reblochon Masque - you can use `place` with `grid` or `pack`. You cannot use `pack` and `grid` together.

Comment: So is there a specific way of doing it?

Comment: Im lost right now

Comment: To make the whole row gray in a specific area

Comment: `Label(..., fg='white', bg='gray').pack(fill='x')`.

Answer (score 1):

Explained in comments.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    #width, height and title are constants of your app so, write them as such
    WIDTH  = 620
    HEIGHT = 400
    TITLE  = 'Arizon'

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        #set the app bg color
        self.configure(bg="gray2")

        #set the header bg color to something different than the app bg color
        header = tk.Label(self, text="Arizon Updater", font="arial 40 bold", fg="gray70", bg="gray18")

        #tell the header to be at the top and to fill it left to right
        header.pack(anchor='nw', fill="x")

        #name things what they are, this is a label, but more importantly it is your first question
        question_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the minimum amount you want to gain: ", font="arial 9 bold", fg="gray70", bg='gray2')
        question_1.place(x=5, y=90)


#use proper PEP8 to initialize your program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.mainloop()
```

**aside:** I fixed the grammar of your fist question.

---

**NOTE:**

Some of what I wrote may seem unnecessary to you, until you realize that every app you ever make can start with the below template. Simply changing `WIDTH`, `HEIGHT` and `TITLE` values sets the stage for whatever you want to build. It's not the "best" template, but it certainly isn't a bad one. When you get better you can make your template better, and understand why it's better.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    WIDTH  = 620
    HEIGHT = 400
    TITLE  = 'Arizon'

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.mainloop()
```

I would highly recommend that you invest some time in reading docs. You will struggle and fail constantly if you don't. Even your successes will be little more than a giant copy/paste mess. Docs are the foundation that you should be building all of your knowledge upon. I've been programming for 25 years, and program in some 20-odd languages proficiently. I have zero StackOverflow questions. I absolutely know what I am talking about. Study the docs like they are the Bible.

*"Tk allowed there to be `Frames`. There were `Frames`, and it was `self.good`"* ~ **The Book Of Docs 1.013rc**

:D